# When creating a java web application, are there benefits to having one's code inside a jar vs. inside the classes folder?

Tags: java, web-applications

In a web-app it is possible to have code in two places:

- WEB-INF/lib
- WEB-INF/classes

In the lib folder, code has to be packaged as a jar file whereas in the classes folder, code is in a folder structure that matches the package structure.

Are there any benefits to putting one's own code as a jar in WEB-INF/lib vs putting it as classes in WEB-INF/classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no benefit. There even are drawbacks:

- creating the jar is one more task to do in your build
- most (all?) of the app servers place the classes directory (or allow placing it) before the jars in the webapp's classpath. So placing your classes and resources there makes sure they are loaded in preference to a similar class or resources located in a jar of WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 0):

JARs only exist to make it easier to move entire applications from one place to another.

Answer (score 0):

That's very poor idea to paste your own classes inside a Jar unless you want to move/supply your code somewhere. Otherwise keep it as it is(WEB-INF/classes). That saves your time and it is standard recommendation.

Remember the other thing that each time you clean your project, new class files generates.

Comment: I meant creating my very own jar not inserting my classes inside someone else's jar. I'm not a parasite :-)

Comment: @DavidBrossard I understood your point and you can do that. No one stops you to do that. What I'm trying to say is, there is no benefits and it eats up some of your time :) For learning/experimenting purpose you are always free to do.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In the past I always did one or the other without giving it a second's thought but today I was like, there must be a proper official way so you all gave me the right answer, thanks